# How to find user Full name without User name in CMD?

Tags: active-directory, command, cmd

I tried this, `net user /domain | find "user1"`, it finds only the user name.

How can I search by the attribute Full Name?

Answer (score 8):

net user "%USERNAME%" /domain | FIND /I "Full Name"

Answer (score 5):

Use `dsquery` instead of `net user` if you want to search by full name. `net user` is not suitable for this kind of query:

```
dsquery user -name "joe average"
```

The command is part of the [Remote Server Management Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7887) (RSAT).

If you already have the username and want to get more information about the user you can use the username directly with `net user`:

```
net user user1 /domain
```